# Darken current background-color dynamically with AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, background-color

**Situation**: I have a table with different background colors for every row.
**Issue**: When I sort the rows by a column I would like to darken a little every `<td>` from that column, based on the `background-color` of the row. Until now I have something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat='row in rows' ng-class="rowClass(row)">
   <td ng-repeat=column in columns"
       ng-style="{'background-color': (isSortedBy(column.key)) ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)' : ''}">
     {{column.text}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

What I do now is just changing the color to a gray (0.05 of black). I can't figure out how to get the current background color of the `<td>` add 0.05 of black over it and apply the new `background-color`. In my project I use `sass` files if it may help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be cleaner to simply apply a class `sorted` and then do the styling with CSS.

`ng-class="{'sorted': (isSortedBy(column.key)) }`

Easier to maintain if all styling is managed through your CSS.

Then you could utilize SASS [`darken()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method) to darken the colors for each column.

Comment: When I have 20 different bgackground-colors it's not a game winner.

Comment: @Leo Not sure what your setup looks like? Are the colors of each column randomized/calculated? If not, I generally think its better to control them through CSS. Having JS affect the look of things is a mix of responsibilities, for most cases.